# Angular 4, ng2-redux: Could not find a declaration file for module 'redux-logger'

Tags: angular, redux

I installed latest Angular from `git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git`

and

```
npm i --save redux-logger redux ng2-redux
```

Here `.../node_modules/redux-logger/src/index.js`
there's

```
export { defaults, createLogger, defaultLogger as logger };
```

**Error:TS7016:Could not find a declaration file for module 'redux-logger'. '.../node_modules/redux-logger/dist/redux-logger.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.**

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
//import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(logger)
);

//const store = createStore(
//  rootReducer,
//  applyMiddleware(createLogger())
//);
```

The same error when using createLogger()

How to fix that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You must be using typescript. In order to import any javascript library/module, you need its corresponding type declarations which are generally included in [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types).

Do:

```
npm i @types/redux-logger --save-dev
```

The package is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/redux-logger).
Then you can import as:

```
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
```